# Symfony1.4 one of few embedded form not saving

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have Bank model with related (one to many) Phone, Social, Service, WorkingHours models. All of them have I18N fields.

I use `ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelations` plugin so rendering and saving of Bank form work well if I render form with `echo $form`.

But I need to render Bank form manually (`echo $form['new_Phones'][0]['en']['value']`) and here I come to problems:

Everything saves well on new Bank form except WorkingHours but it is certainly the same as other models. And then on edit form I have only Bank fields filled in.

I've been fightint with this problem for two days now. Could someone help me, please?

Here is pieces of code:
schema: http://pastie.org/2861044
form classes: http://pastie.org/2861072
form template: http://pastie.org/2861070

Comment: If it works when you use `echo $form`, then you should try to spot hidden fields that might be necessary and you omitted.

Comment: It would be a good idea to cut your code pieces to the minimum related length and include them in the question instead of linking to a 3rd party site.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in WorkingHours. It had only one field wich was i18n. Adding second not i18n field is dirty hack but now it works. I think it's bug in plugin or in symfony.